# iOS - Programatically add a new view to work with my storyboard autolayout viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, autolayout

I am using Storyboards with autolayout where I have a viewcontroller full of views, buttons, labels, a table...

I want to create a new View at the top of this view, below the navigationbar, when a button is clicked, and hide it after clicking again over it.

I want to do this programatically. This means that this view will appear at the top and the rest of the views will have to move down the height of that new view. When this view disappears the views will move up again.

What'd be the best approach to do this? I've tried to create a view in the storyboard with height = 0 and change the height in code. Is there a better way for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi as you are using auto layout I would suggest taking an IBOutlet for the height constraint of the view that you want to put below the navigation bar and change it in code

Here is a sample

```
//IBOutlet for height constraint of view

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *conHeightTopView;

- (void)changeHeight:(BOOL)change{
    if (change) {

        _conHeightTopView.constant = 50;//Height of view when shown

    }else{
        _conHeightTopView.constant = 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: That's what I did, yeah. Thanks!

Comment: but with one line: - (void)changeHeight:(BOOL)change {
        _conHeightTopView.constant = change ? 50 : 0;
} ;)

Answer (score 0):

All the views that need to be moved down should be put in one `UIView`. And your code should have an IBOutlet for this view.

When you create your new view programmatically, you will know it's height.

Now you can call `setFrame` of your first view and move it down.